# Finding a transformation with respect to a basis - does this question have no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have a problem that says:

Let 
$$V =
\left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}
\text{| $x +y+z = 0$} 
\right\}
$$
$$W =
\left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}
\text{| $x +y = 0$} 
\right\}
$$
Find a basis for $V$ and $W$, called $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Find $_\beta[T]_\alpha$, where $T : V \rightarrow W$ is defined by:
$$T 
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x - y\\
y + z\\
y - x\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But is $T$ actually a transformation from $V$ to $W$? Because $(x-y) + (y + z) = x + z = -y$, which is not necessarily $0$. Am I just missing something here, or misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are correct, the problem is iill posed. Note that $v=(1,1,-2)^T \in V$ but $Tv = (0,-2, 0)^T \notin W$.

Comment: I believe that you’re completely correct. A general element of $V$ is $(a,b,-b-a)$, and its image under $T$ is $(a-b,-a,b-a)$, which will not be in $W$ unless $b=0$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Was trying to solve it and ran into issues, didn't know if I just messed up with selecting $\alpha$ and $\beta$ somehow or if the problem was wrong.